# Function from composable used in two other composables

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've `useCountdown` composable:

```js
const TIME_LIMIT = 180

export default () => {
  const timePassed = ref(0)
  const timerInterval = ref(null)

  const timeLeft = computed(() => TIME_LIMIT - timePassed.value)

  const formattedTimeLeft = computed(() => {
    const _timeLeft = timeLeft.value
    const minutes = Math.floor(_timeLeft / 60)
    let seconds = _timeLeft % 60

    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = `0${seconds}` as unknown as number
    }

    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`
  })

  const startTimer = () => {
    timerInterval.value = setInterval(() => (timePassed.value += 1), 1000)
  }

  const onTimesUp = () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval.value)
    timePassed.value = 0
    timerInterval.value = null
    startTimer()
  }

  watch(timeLeft, (newVal) => {
    if (newVal === 0) {
      onTimesUp()
    }
  })

  onMounted(() => startTimer())

  return {
    formattedTimeLeft,
    startTimer,
    onTimesUp,
  }
}
```

On application init counter starts, but I also need to use `startTimer` and `onTimesUp` in other composable when I get some event.

I want to display `formattedTimeLeft` in some component but when I get event which should call `onTimesUp` then `startTimer`, `formattedTimeLeft` doesn't change in Header.

How to make globally available `formattedTimeLeft`?

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api]

Comment: @EstusFlask I changed to reactive but still functions aren't call when event comes

Comment: The point here is that reactive/ref vars should be defined outside the function. What exactly did you do and in which way did it not work?

Comment: @EstusFlask ok, nvm. I took all refs, startTimer and onTimesUp functions outside function and made them reactive. now everything works fine. thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening before on composable will be re-created in every component you use it. It's like a `Class`, imagine every time you call `useCountdown()` it will create a new instance e.g. `new ClassName()`.

To make composable "shared" you could move all the state outside

```
const timePassed = ref(0)
const timerInterval = ref(null)
const timeLeft = computed(() => ...)
const formattedTimeLeft = computed(() => ...)

const useCountdown = () => {
  ...
  return {
    formattedTimeLeft
  }
}
```

Or if you're using VueUse just use this -https://vueuse.org/shared/createSharedComposable/

Wish you luck!